# conditionally load js file with screen width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the below java-script which loads the screen as per the resolution and js file.
But I have to refresh the browser to reload the js file as per resolution otherwise it keeps the last resolution js file.

Please help me to understand how to load both at once.

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function( callback ){ window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60); };
})();

var width = screen.width,
    height = screen.height,
    checkScreenSize = function () {
        if (screen.width !== width || screen.height !== height) {
            width = screen.width;
            height = screen.height;
            $(window).trigger('resolutionchange');
        }
    };

(function loop(){
  requestAnimFrame(loop);
  checkScreenSize();
})();

function includeJS(incFile) {
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="'+ incFile+ '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
}

if (window.matchMedia("only screen and (min-width: 1240px) and (max-width: 1280px)").matches) {
    includeJS('changer/js/changer-1280.js');
} else if (window.matchMedia("only screen and (min-width: 1390px) and (max-width: 1440px)").matches) {
    includeJS('changer/js/changer-1440.js');
} else if (window.matchMedia("only screen and (min-width: 1441px) and (max-width: 1441px)").matches) {
    includeJS('changer/js/changer-1441.js');
}
```

Comment: Depending on the size of your scripts, you are probably better off with just putting the pieces in if statements and loading the whole script (minified etc of course) -

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to watch the window resize event maybe? Something like this:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  if (window.matchMedia("only screen and (min-width: 1240px) and (max-width: 1280px)").matches) {
    $.getScript('changer/js/changer-1280.js');
  } else if (window.matchMedia("only screen and (min-width: 1390px) and (max-width: 1440px)").matches) {
    $.getScript('changer/js/changer-1440.js');
  } else if (window.matchMedia("only screen and (min-width: 1441px) and (max-width: 1441px)").matches) {
    $.getScript('changer/js/changer-1441.js');
  }
});
```

Since you're using jQuery anyway, you can use its `$.getScript` instead of injecting the script element manually.

I see there's some code there that seems to watch the window height and width to implement a custom window resize event. That's not really necessary though. I think you would especially not want to do that during a RAF loop like that since it's probably triggering a layout during every single frame.

Running those matchMedia checks every time the window's resize event fires will bog down resizing performance too, so you should debounce and only handle the event after there's a pause in resizing. Something like this:

```
var resizeTimer;

$(window).on('resize', function() {
  clearTimeout(resizeTimer);

  // Wait half a second before reacting to the resize event,
  //  in case the user is still actively resizing the window.
  resizeTimer = setTimeout(handleWindowResize, 500);
});

function handleWindowResize() {
  if (window.matchMedia("only screen and (min-width: 1240px) and (max-width: 1280px)").matches) {
    $.getScript('changer/js/changer-1280.js');
  } else if (window.matchMedia("only screen and (min-width: 1390px) and (max-width: 1440px)").matches) {
    $.getScript('changer/js/changer-1440.js');
  } else if (window.matchMedia("only screen and (min-width: 1441px) and (max-width: 1441px)").matches) {
    $.getScript('changer/js/changer-1441.js');
  }
}
```

Comment: well i tried it the problem is still there i want to change the js file along with the resolution change. it is loading the css of the current resolution but to reload the js file i have to refresh the page then it loads the current resolution js file

Comment: @Malangi: Maybe the JavaScript in the changer-nnnn.js files isn't running immediately when they're loaded and requires some sort of event or function call to trigger? Can you post the contents of one of them?

Comment: @Malangi: If possible, it would be best to update your question to add it. Otherwise, maybe somewhere like pastebin or a GitHub gist.

Comment: @Malangi: A couple things. First, you should definitely separate the resolution-specific code from the code that doesn't change and the cookie plugin. You don't want to reload that every time the resolution changes. To the problem you're dealing with, I think that code will need to be modified in order to work more than once per page load. Right now, it looks like it's appending duplicates every time which, depending on your CSS, may not be visible.

Comment: even then not working would you please give me an example with my code

Comment: @Malangi: The example I gave you would work if the code in changer-nnn.js handled running twice on the same page load. If you look at the network tab in your browser's dev tools, you should see the file being loaded when you resize past certain breakpoints.

Comment: i can not understand i tried but fails... would you please again reset the code if you have time please??